# Page Objects - level of abstraction for methods

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I searched around on the internet a bit but thought I might get some insight by just posting on stackoverflow and seeing if there were any opinions out there.

I'm wondering if anyone has an opinion of which is preferred between these two ways of setting up a page object:

```
public class LoginPage extends PageObject{
   public void typeEmail(String email){
       driver.findElement(EMAIL_SELECTOR).sendKeys(email);
   }

   public void typePassword(String pw){
       driver.findElement(PASSWORD_SELECTOR).sendKeys(email);
   }

   public void submit(){
       driver.findElement(SUBMIT_SELECTOR).click();
   }
}
```

...and...

```
public class LoginPage extends PageObjects{
    public void login(String email, String password){
       driver.findElement(EMAIL_SELECTOR).sendKeys(email);
       driver.findElement(PASSWORD_SELECTOR).sendKeys(email);
       driver.findElement(SUBMIT_SELECTOR).click();
   }
}
```

Originally, I thought the second way would be better since if the login flow changes for some reason (this is unlikely with a login, but you could theorize this happening for other types of forms), you could update the login() method and this change would affect all the tests which required login.

However, if you want to verify error conditions or more things before submit(), the second solution isn't flexible enough.

Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: The second solution is more 'page-object' like. The idea is they should represent **services** your page can do. As in, 'login' is the overarching service/action it can do, underneath that it must type the username and password and click OK. However, exposed to the public callers is only the 'login' method. They don't get to know 'how' it 'logs in'. What exactly isn't flexible about it?

Comment: Also, the latter approach is what the architect of the Page Object pattern intended. The former approach is, by his definition, not a Page Object.

Comment: how then might you make the approach flexible enough to allow for verification of things before you hit submit? For example, say you fill out a form and then you get a preview and you want to be able to verify different items on that preview? You would not want to do this every test, but just in specific ones.

Comment: @Arran: Curious where do you normally put your asserts? Inside `Login()`? Create `AssertLogin()` in the page? Throw them in the test body after calling `Login()`?

Comment: @user1177636, I would say (unsure if this is 'true' Page Object style) that assertions are the responsibility of your tests themselves. The page object should not 'know' about assertions and should never perform them. You should simply expose properties, methods or whatever needed to allow you to make your assertion in the test. The page object should be only concerned about the page itself, what it can do and how it's 'made up'.

Answer (score 1):

Page object definition :  *"A PageObject need not represent an entire page. It may represent a section that appears many times within a site or page, such as site navigation."*

The keys points of a PageObject :

```
- The public methods represent the services that the page offers
- Try not to expose the internals of the page
- Generally don't make assertions
- Methods return other PageObjects
- Need not represent an entire page
- Different results for the same action are modelled as different methods
```

[SOURCE](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

Your two settings aren't PageObject but there is some similarities.

Comment: What do you mean by, "Your two settings aren't PageObject but there is some similarities."?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to use another level of abstraction like:

```
public void typeEmail(String email){
       fillField(EMAIL_SELECTOR, email);
   }
```

**And an implementation in your SeleniumWrapper class**

```
public void fillField(WebElement selector, String text){
       driver.findElement(selector).sendKeys(text);
   }
```

This makes code more good-looking

This is not directly related to PageObjects, but still this is a way to prettify your code if you dont use BDD, or keyword-driven approach